# Blank bar at the bottom of a page

Tags: html, css

I've been working on a few sites, and for some reason, a blank bar keeps showing up at the bottom. I've tried inspecting the elements, and I get nothing that makes any sense. html and body elements are set for margin: 0 and padding: 0.

Any ideas on how to remove the blank bar at the bottom?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `&nbsp;` from your clearfixing divs. Even with the `height:0`, the space character is taking up space. One you remove it, the div will collapse properly.

Answer (score 0):

Probably way off here and I'm not sure but one of the plugins you are using is placing a smiley at the bottom of the page. I think it is popular posts that does this.

Have your tried disabling the plugins one by one to see if this goes?

Comment: The smiley is the Wordpress stats plugin, but the smiley should be hidden.